# How to make click button from js script in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to click checkbox from one of my function of script but i do not know how to do it in angularjs?

I have tried following way but it is not working :
**JS**

```
var a = document.getElementById("selectAllElem");
$scope.selectAll = a["onclick"];
if (typeof($scope.selectAll) == "function") {
    alert("call click");
    $scope.selectAll(a);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="selectAll($event)" id="selectAllElem" />
```

Can anyone show  me how to  make checkbox click from js script in angularjs?

**UPDATE**

I can not use just single flag variable because above checkbox is placed at header of table and on click of it i need to make all selected check box as deselect and deselected check box as selected.
I need to call button click to achieve target.

how to  make checkbox click from js script in angularjs?

Comment: In AngularJS model drives the view behavious. See this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

You can bind scope variables to all checkboxes and change them in the selectAll() method handling the click.
Also, you could then bind a method to the selectAllElem checkbox, checking if all other checkboxes are selected.
I renamed selectAll() to toggleAll() to show how to select/deselect in one method.

e.g.:

```
<input ... ng-click="toggleAll()" ng-model="allSelected()" />
```

and

```
$scope.allSelected = function(){
  return $scope.option1 && $scope.option2;
}
$scope.toggleAll = function(){
  var value = !$scope.allSelected();
  $scope.option1 = value;
  $scope.option2 = value;
}
```

In case of the checkboxes being generated from an array, you can have scope.options and iterate over it in both methods.

**OLD**

You could bind the input to a scope variable, e.g.:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="selectAll($event)" id="selectAllElem" ng-model="allSelected" />
```

And then set that variable from within the function

$scope.allSelected = true;

Answer (score 0):

you can use this instead of above code :

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="selectAll()" id="selectAllElem" ng-model="allSelected" />
```

in controller create function selectAll():

```
$scope.selectAll=function(){
   $scope.allSelected=true;
 }
```